# C# with SQL Combination Serach with many conditions and big Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, combinations

I need help to optimize the query for my combination search.
I have a string with and values I have a search like (Hello World)
Now the program need to search in 7 fields for the Value Hello and then the program need to search in this 7 fields again if one of the fields contain World, so I have only rows with Hello in 1 field and World in the same or other field. The Table where I search has 50000 rows and every day more. At this time I split the searchcondition at space then I have a array of searchconditions. For every searchcondition in this array I use 7 OR and add it to the query string. So my Querystring is very big and has many OR.
I now want to optimize my Query and Code so I get faster result of the Query.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Version 10.50.2500.0

Answer (score 1):

LIKE operator isn't very fast - given the multiple columns and growing table size I recommend you to take a look at having FULLTEXT service+index over your DB and perform your search using fulltext index instead.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms142571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use "like" queries for seven fields.
It is also not good if you search with %string%, because like is working fast with string% but not %string.

Use full-text search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx